# What underlying semantic notions connect 'rēs' to 'reus'?

Tags: etymology

Wiktionary asserts the etymon of [reus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reus#Latin) as [rēs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/res#Latin). But how might have 'rēs' shifted semantically to mean 'reus'?

My conjecture: If I ignore the morality and subjectivity of something 'guilty', then one can consider something guilty as a thing, matter, or affair; but  this conjecture is outstretching the Semantic Field of 'reus' and feels too feigned.

Comment: *Res* can specifically mean a court case or lawsuit, which would make the connection a natural one. That said, apparently there is not a consensus that *reus* dervies from *res* (de Vaan implies that Ernout-Meillet reject the connection).

Comment: Note that [_reus_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dreus) means _accused_ rather than (or prior to) _guilty_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Ernout's Dictionnaire etymologique de la langue latine, *reus* properly means "he who is related to the *res*", with *res* meaning *object (contended in this court case)*. Originally the word meant "the defender in a court case" or also "the accused one"; only later it came to the meaning of "guilty" (accused > suspected of being guilty > guilty) which is carried on by Romance languages.